# How to find the index of remaining columns if the data is repetitive

Tags: excel

I have a data entry like this[Data entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q2gw.jpg)

[image]

Now, i need to find the smallest 10 values and also get the corresponding person and area and date along with it.
I used SMALL functoin to find the least 10 values. Then I used the index and match functions for getting their corresponding row entries. The problem is since some data entries are being repetitive, these functions are giving the row of the first 2 for all the remaining 2s. How to solve this

Answer (score 1):

In F2 use Rank like this, so you have unique numbers:

```
=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$21,1)+ROW()/1000
```

in G2 use Small, to pull the smallest of the ranked numbers and copy down 10 rows.

```
=SMALL($F$2:$F$21,ROW(A1))
```

Now you can pull person, date, real hours and area with an index match in H2, copied across and down.

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$21,MATCH($G2,$F$2:$F$21,0))
```

[image]